# Syntax for X-Forwarded_server for Apache

Tags: apache

Can anyone let me know the syntax for the X-forwarded-Server,X-Forwarded-For and X-forwarded-Host in httpd.conf file.
My requirement is I am using an Apache server which has Siteminder webagent associated to it and I want to forwarded the  proxy server name to Siteminder policy servers,can anyone please help on how to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: " forwarded the proxy server name to Siteminder policy servers" - Do you mean that the policy server audit log should contain the value for X-Forwarded-For header as client IP ?

Answer (score 0):

These headers are added when you use the mod_proxy_http module. First, check for these modules in httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then do something like this in your server.conf file.

```
ProxyPass       /app1/  http://internal1.example.com/
ProxyPass       /app2/  http://internal2.example.com/
```

Here is the Apache doc for the same.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

You can add the headers to the reverse proxy by :

```
ProxyPassReverse  "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
```

Comment: The mod_proxy_htttp module and mod_proxy modules are enabled.

Comment: Then did you add a proxy pass to your server conf?

Comment: Yes the ProxyPass  is added and tested and I have done it several times.

Comment: If you want to add the headers on top of adding the reverse proxy then use ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://internal1.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://internal2.example.com/

Comment: I was not trying to get info on how to configure ProxyPass , I was trying to get info on how to configure X-forwarded-Server.

Comment: You need to read this link https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

Comment: When acting in a reverse-proxy mode (using the ProxyPass directive, for example), mod_proxy_http adds several request headers in order to pass information to the origin server. These headers are:

X-Forwarded-For
The IP address of the client.
X-Forwarded-Host
The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
X-Forwarded-Server
The hostname of the proxy server.

Comment: Thank you for the link but it doesn't talk about the syntax which I need for X-forwarded-Server in httpd.conf ,can you please post the syntax if you have it.